# Why wireless switch has different load rating for led vs incandescent

Tags: led

I have a wireless switch that is rated to 60 W LED/CFL and 100 W incandescent lighting. I understand incandescents are more tolerant to high temperatures than are leds. But, why would that affect the wireless switch? It isn’t stated as 60 W equivalent LED which would require less than 10 W.

Answer (score 3):

> *Why wireless switch has different load rating for led vs incandescent*

I suspect it has a lot to do with the power factor associated with older CFL and LED lamps. Here's a quote from any.lamp.com entitled [What does the power factor of a light source mean?](https://www.any-lamp.com/blog/what-does-the-power-factor-mean#:%7E:text=The%20power%20factor%20of%20a%20light%20source%20indicates%20how%20much,can%20be%200.3%2C%20for%20example.): -

> The power factor of a light source indicates how much blind current is
> generated. The power factor is calculated by dividing the apparent
> power with the actual power. The power factor of an incandescent light
> bulb is 1, the apparent power and actual power are even. But the power
> factor of LED can be 0.3, for example. The apparent power is higher
> than the actual power and the light source produces blind current.
> This blind current is sent back into the power network, causing
> pollution.

So, with a poor power factor the actual peak current taken may be much larger than that implied by the wattage of an incandescent lamp. And. of course, the power factor is due to rectifiers and smoothing capacitor circuits used within these devices. See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp#:%7E:text=Voltage%20and%20current%20for%20a,this%20lamp%20is%20only%200.61.) for details of a CFL lamp: -

[image]

> Voltage and current for a 120 V 60 Hz 30-watt compact fluorescent
> lamp. Because the current is heavily distorted, the power factor of
> this lamp is only 0.61. The lamp takes 29 watts, but 39 volt-amperes
> due to this distortion.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about inrush current.

LED and CFL lights typically has some capacitors on its input, that can cause a huge inrush current for a brief moment when it is connected to power. This causes a lot of stress on the switch.

Incandescent lights don't have any capacitors, and much lower inrush current.

Comment: To put that into scale, much lower inrush for incandescents means only about 10 to 20 times the nominal current. While LEDs consume less, the caps can still draw even higher inrush than incandescents.

Comment: The resistance of the tungsten filament is only a few ohms when cold but 50 ohms when hot.

Comment: @Justme For ~2700 K, the inrush is about 12 times the steady-state current.

Answer (score 0):

Relays have different ratings for different types of loads.

A load can be purely resistive like imdandescents and heaters, or inductive like anything with motors, or capacitive like anythiny with a switch mode power supply.

In addition to power factor how these consume current vs voltage under steady state, there is a factor of what happens when switching loads.

While incandescent lamps are resiastive, they take 10x to 20x the rated current when turned on because the filament is cold and the rated current is drawn only when filament is hot.

LED lamps have generally a power supply of some kind in them, and in some lamps the worst case is that the mains is directly rectified into capacitor, so the inrush is very large.